# onto homomorphic mapping from $Z_4 $ to $Z_2 \times Z_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

The external direct product of groups $G$ and $H$ is the same group 
    $$ G \times H  = \{ (g,h)\| g \in G , h \in H\} $$
whose operation is defined componentwise, that is,

$(g_1,h_1)(g_2,h_2)=(g_1g_2,h_1h_2)$ for all $g_1,g_2 \in G $

and for all $h_1,h_2 \in H$. Is there a homomorphism from $Z_4$ to $Z_2 \times Z_2$ that is surjective (i.e onto)? If so, specify it.

---

**attempt 1]** know that $Z_4$ is cyclic  and $Z_2xZ_2$ is not so they wont be isomorphic something is failing either not homorphic, into or bijective at the least

trying to play with something like $f:Z_4 \to Z_2 \times Z_2$ by $f(z)=([z]_{k_1},[z]_{k_2})$ not sure what the external direct product has to do with it.

read from similar post that the order of the kernel is two so i dont think there is one that is onto

[Question about method of finding homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_4$ to $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783755/question-about-method-of-finding-homomorphisms-from-mathbb-z-4-to-mathbb-z)

---

Comment: Reference, recall, or prove (!!) the almost-trivial statement that the homomorphic image of a cyclic group is cyclic. Then you have your answer, since you said you know already the right-had side group is not cyclic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both groups are finite and of the same size, hence surjectivity implies injectivity using the pigeonhole principle. Hence, requiring a homomorphism that is surjective actually requires an isomorphism. Contradict that with your reasoning that the groups won't be isomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

A homomorphic image of a cyclic group is always cyclic but $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ is not cyclic.